# Inverse Fourier transform for moments

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Let us consider the Fourier  transform for a continious function  $f(x)$ $\lim\limits_{ x \to \pm \infty} f(x)=0$:
$$
\mathcal{F}\{f(x) \}=F(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i ux} dx
$$
We have

\begin{gather*}
F(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i ux} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2\pi i ux)^n}{n!} dx=\\=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-2\pi i u)^n}{n!} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) x^n dx=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-2\pi i u)^n}{n!} \mu_n,
\end{gather*}
where
$$
\mu_n=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) x^n dx.
$$

I want now  to find the $\mu_n$ by using the inverse Fourier  transform.

I know that $\mu_n$   can be found directly using the formula
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{\int f(x) x^n \right\}=\frac{\mathcal{F}\{ f(x) x^n  \}}{2 \pi x}
$$
but this way is not suitable, because then we  have to find  $\mathcal{F}\{ f(x) x^n  \}$  for any $n$ separately.

Therefore I try to find a function  $X(u)$ such that
$$
\mu_n=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{ F(u) X(u) \}(n)
$$
I tried to expand  $ X (u) $ in a series to find its coefficients  but without success.

**Question:**  Is is possible to find the $X(u)$  in a simple uniform way?

P.S. We can consider $ f $ not only as a continuous function but as  smooth and more.

Answer (score 1):

That $f$ is continuous isn't enough for the Fourier transform integral to converge. If $x^n f\in L^1$ for $n\le k$ then $F(u)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2i\pi u x}f(x)dx$ is $C^k$ and $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty (-2i\pi x)^n f(x)dx= F^{(n)}(0)$ for $n\le k$.

If this holds for all $k$ then $F$ is smooth.

The condition for the Taylor series to converge and $F$ being equal to its Taylor series (analytic) is much more restrictive, a sufficient condition is that $f$ has exponential decay.

Comment: Ok, let $f$ be smooth, no matter for me. I correct the text

Comment: That $f$ is smooth doesn't change anything. You need $f$ being integrable as well as $x^n f$ for all $n$.

Comment: What conditions must be  for $f$  to avoid the integration?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? $x^n f\in L^1$ means $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x^n f(x)|dx<\infty$, if so then the integrals are well-defined without problems and it remains to show that  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-2i\pi x)^n f(x)dx= F^{(n)}(0)$

Comment: I dont want intergate for any $n$, I want to find the function $X(u)$  to get $\mu$  for all $n$ after only one inverse transformation.

Comment: $(-2i\pi x)^n f(x)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $F^{(n)}(u)$ (assuming the Fourier inversion theorem holds, ie. assuming more conditions on $f$) not of $F(u)X(u)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas have a few a typos scattered about, but if I'm understanding you correctly then we can use the FT instead of the inverse FT more directly

$$ \mu_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n f(x) e^{-2\pi i \cdot 0 \cdot x} dx $$ $$= \frac{1}{(-2\pi i)^n}\frac{d^n}{du^n} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi \cdot 0 \cdot x}dx = \frac{F^{(n)}(0)}{(-2\pi i)^n}$$

Which gives you the Taylor series formula when you plug into the summation.

Comment: Maybe there must be the variable $u$ -- $e^{-2\pi i 0 u}$?

Comment: and $\mu_n$ must be real numbers not complex

Comment: @Leox $u$ is exactly as you have defined it. And this is real, why do you think otherwise.

Comment: I think that $\frac{F^{(n)}(0)}{(-2\pi i)^n}$ is a complex number

Comment: @Leox then you think wrong. It equals a real integral, it has to be real